# Infinite cycle in code

Tags: c

I am new to C and currently doing a BREP (boundary representation) implementation in C, the idea is: given a topology matrix and a vertex matrix to produce ordered tables with information of the connectivity of the solid. The problem I have is in these two loops:

**main loop**

```
 while(next < n_triang)
{
    /* extract the triangle to be used and the next in queue */
    next = extract_next(grid_triang, n_triang, next, &current_triang);

    /* set triang_vertex as the current triangle */
    for(i = 0; i < VERTEX_COUNT; i++)
    {
        triang_vertex[i] = (int)grid_triang[current_triang][i];
    }

    /* find the orientation of the current triangle */
    orientation_wrong = find_connection(triang_vertex, grid_edges, &n_edges, &partner_triang, &partner_edge);

    /* if there is no partner triangle, set status to free */
    if(partner_triang == FALSE)
    {
        grid_triang[current_triang][USE_INDEX] = TRIANG_FREE;
    }
    else
    {
        /* if orientation is wrong, change the order of vertex and add the triangle to the mesh */
        if( orientation_wrong == TRUE)
        {
            temp = triang_vertex[Y_];
            triang_vertex[Y_] = triang_vertex[Z_];
            triang_vertex[Z_] = temp;

            for(i=0; i<VERTEX_COUNT; i++)
            {
                grid_triang[current_triang][i] = (float)triang_vertex[i];
            }

            add_triangle(triang_vertex, next, grid_vertex, grid_edges, &current_triang, &n_edges);

            /* add the current triangle to the faces grid */
            for (i = 0; i < n_points; i++)
            {
                grid_faces[i][current_triang] = triang_vertex[i];
            }           
        }
        else
        {
            /* if orientation is correct, add the triangle to the mesh and to the faces grid */
            add_triangle(triang_vertex, next, grid_vertex, grid_edges, &current_triang, &n_edges);

            for (i = 0; i < VERTEX_COUNT; i++)
            {
                grid_faces[i][current_triang] = triang_vertex[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**extract_next function**

```
 int extract_next(float **grid_triang, int n_triang, int next, int *current_triang)
{
/* define variables */
int new_next = 0, visited_triang = 0, kill = 0;
int found_triang = FALSE;

/* if triangle is used throw error */
if(grid_triang[next][USE_INDEX] == TRIANG_USED )
{
    perror("Current triangle not available");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
else *current_triang = next; /* set current triangle to output */

/* change status to used */
grid_triang[next][USE_INDEX] = TRIANG_USED;
next++;

/* start the iteration */
while(!found_triang && visited_triang < n_triang)
{
        /* if triangle is used, go to next triangle and add a visited */
    if(grid_triang[next][USE_INDEX] == TRIANG_USED)
    {
        next++;
        visited_triang++;
        printf("Used, moving");
    }
    else if(grid_triang[next][USE_INDEX] == TRIANG_FREE)
    {
            /* if triangle is free then break the loop */
        found_triang = TRUE;
        printf("found a free one!\n");
    }
    else printf("not valid");

}

/* if found triangle set the next triangle to output */
if (found_triang)
{
    new_next = next;
}

printf("New triangle extracted\n");
return new_next;
```

}

The code should stop execution when variable **next** equals **n_triang**, but the code keeps executing indefinitely and I cannot figure why (even with debugging step by step). Here is the output:

[image]

As you can see, when it reaches the value of **n_triang**, it should stop but instead continues indefinitely.

Thanks to anyone that can help.

Comment: Here is some general advice for debugging a `while` loop. Your stop condition is `next < n_triang`. At each loop, check the value of both `next` and `n_triang`. I would put a `printf("%d", next)` and a `printf("%d", n_triang)` at both the very beginning and the very end of the loop. This will help you find why `next < n_triang` is never (or not when you expect it) met.

Comment: found/not found/etc messages aren't helpful - add variable values to you `printf()`s. Specifically your return value as it's assigned to `next` and also `n_triang`

Comment: I would suggest that you convert any and all comparisons of a variable with `TRUE` or `FALSE` to the form:  `if (variable) {` or `if (!variable) {`. In particular, C considers *any* non-zero value to be "true". So if you're comparing with `TRUE` (which is probably #define'd to be 1) and some function returns 7, the behavior won't be what you expect.

Comment: `while(!found_triang && visited_triang < n_triang)` In the *"not valid"* case both these condtions are loop-invariant. Also: strong advice *not* to use indicator variables. Vote with your feet: break out of the loop instead.

Comment: Your function returns 0 when a triangle is not found. Is this what you want?

Comment: `TRIANG_USED` and `TRIANG_FREE` seem to cover all relevant states. What is the third value? Do you have a simple initialization error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your problem lies here:

```
/* start the iteration */
while(!found_triang && visited_triang < n_triang)
{
        /* if triangle is used, go to next triangle and add a visited */
    if(grid_triang[next][USE_INDEX] == TRIANG_USED)
    {
        next++;
        visited_triang++;
        printf("Used, moving");
    }
    else if(grid_triang[next][USE_INDEX] == TRIANG_FREE)
    {
            /* if triangle is free then break the loop */
        found_triang = TRUE;
        printf("found a free one!\n");
    }
    else printf("not valid");

}

/* if found triangle set the next triangle to output */
if (found_triang)
{
    new_next = next;
}

printf("New triangle extracted\n");
return new_next;
```

You are testing if triangles are used/unused, which suggests that you think the triangles are some kind of "memory pool." This is fine.

However, you do not constrain your index variable (`next`) to stay within the range of the pool. I believe you're getting a fairly high starting point, and walking off the end of your array.

I suggest you add some index checking, and wrap your index back to zero when needed:

```
#define TRIANGLE_USED(n) (grid_triang[(n)][USE_INDEX] == TRIANG_USED)

for (n_visited = 0; n_visited < n_triang; ++n_visited)
{
    // The `next` variable is an index into a pool of triangles.
    // Don't overrun the pool - reset to the bottom if needed.
    if (next >= n_triang) {
        next = 0;
    }

    if (TRIANGLE_USED(next)) {
        printf("Triangle %d is used. Skipping.", next);          
        ++next;
    }        
    else {
        printf("Triangle %d is free. Stopping.", next);
        break;
    }
    /*NOTREACHED*/
}

return next;
```